# binary operation `|` cannot be applied to type

Tags: rust

I have this error

> error: binary operation `|` cannot be applied to type `&mut u16`

With this code,

```
fn f_op(op: &mut u16) {

    let mut addr: u16 = (op | 0xFFF);
    ..//
}
```

Solve it change `&mut` to `&`

```
fn f_op(op: & u16) {
```

But I wonder why I can not use `|` with `&mut`, sure there exists a good reason, but someone can explain to me.

<kbd>[Play-Rust](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f0c3f998171e9bfa77d6fec94807911b&version=stable&backtrace=0)</kbd>

Comment: Since most primitives (including u16) impl Copy it's more idiomatic to just take them by value since they'll be copied, afaict

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the [BitOr trait is not implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.BitOr.html) for `&mut u16`.. however, it is for `&u16`.

[image: BitOr trait]

As viraptor points out, you could also dereference it with:

```
*op | 0xFFF;
```

.. which would make it a `u16`.. which also implements the `BitOr` trait as you can see above.

Comment: Now I know that there is no apparent reason to implement, using *, but could be implemented for &mut, it's just a hypothetical question

Comment: @AngelAngel Well, sure, you *could* implement it for `&mut`.  And `Box`.  And `Rc`.  And `Arc`.  And `P` (used in `rustc`).  And `Cell`.  And `*const`.  And `*mut`.  There are probably more, but you have to *stop* at some point; might as well be the minimal set.

Comment: @DK. Sure, but *I think* that implementing it only for immutable references is pretty arbitrary and leads to confusion :/  Implementing it for raw pointers is highly unsafe. So with an impl for `&mut`, `BitOr` would be implemented for all safe primitive types.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to `or` the value, not the reference.

```
let mut addr: u16 = *op | 0xFFF;
```